# How can I set a value after getting the object from the data base?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the object called `FighterModel` and in my repository's service I get the properties from SQL Server.

```
public class FighterModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int QtyMartialArts { get; set; }
    public int QtyDefeats { get; set; }
    public int QtyVictories { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int QtyFights { get; set; }
}
```

I want the `QtyFights` be the sum of `QtyVictories` and `QtyDefeats`, how can I do this, after getting the data from the entity?

I tried to do a function and set in the constructor but it does not work.

```
public class FighterModel
{
    public FighterModel() 
    {
        AtualizaLutas();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int QtyMartialArts { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int QtyFights { get; set; }

    public int QtyDefeats { get; set; }
    public int QtyVictories { get; set; }

    private void AtualizaLutas()
    {
        QtyFights = QtyVictories + QtyDefeats;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it directly. This is if you don't need to set the values for QtyFights

```
[NotMapped]
public int QtyFights => QtyVictories + QtyDefeats;
```

Comment: His code also has a  setter. Just an arrow function makes it read only. You might wanna update it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a private getter instead of the function

> Properties are declared in the class block by specifying the access
> level of the field, followed by the type of the property, followed by
> the name of the property, and followed by a code block that declares a
> get-accessor and/or a set accessor.

```
public int QtyFights 
{
    get { return QtyVictories + QtyDefeats; };
    set { name = value; }
}
```

[Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties)

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties)

EDIT: But if you wanted to use a function to override.

```
public int QtyFights 
{
    get => AtualizaLutas();
    set { name = value; }
}

public virtual int AtualizaLutas()
{
   return QtyVictories + QtyDefeats;
}
```

if you make it public and virtual, you can let the caller override the function with what ever they want.

Comment: I think the _set_ part has no business here

Comment: His code above has a getter and setter, so I set it off of his example.

Comment: That's seems more a quick copy/paste than a reasonable requirement. If you always return a calculated value, mark the property as [NotMapped] then you probably and logically don't have and shouldn't have a place where you call the _set_ property

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work in the constructor because the property binding is done after instance creation. You are trying to sum the default value of "**QtyVictories**" and "**QtyDefeats**" of type "integer" which equals **zero(0)**. It means, **QtyFights** value always remains **zero(0)**.

**Just declare property only has getter like below:**

```
public int QtyFights { get { return QtyVictories + QtyDefeats; } }
```